# ajax control toolkit fileupload control for selecting multiple files

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, .net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using asp.net ajax control toolkit's file upload control. The control is designed to select a single file. But I have made changes to made it to select multiple file by accessing

```
<input type='file'>
```

and adding 'multiple' attribute.

I am changing attribute using jquery like this

```
 $("#AsyncFileUpload1_ctl02").attr("multiple", "multiple");
```

I need to know the "id" of input field inside ajax fileupload controls remains same or it changes?

Comment: If you are not using `ClientIDMode="Static"` then control's ID will change. Use `$("#<%=AsyncFileUpload1.ClientID%>")`.

Comment: What is id of input ?

Comment: @MairajAhmad fileupload from ajax control toolkit wrapped in a div and inside that div you will find the actual input with type=file. so the "id" belongs to that input

Comment: @صفيActually clientidmode of name of ajax control is really nothing but id of a div. magic lies inside that div "so called the actual input type=file"

Comment: Please post the whole input code.